# How to get parent function in es6 javascript classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I have something like

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.test = function(){return 1;};
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super(); 
        this.test = function(){alert(  super.test()   );};
    }
}
```

This does not work, but is there a way I can access the parent function test()?

Comment: Does it work if they're actual methods? Could you give more context on the need to create these in the constructor?

Comment: I wanted them in constructor because then I can do private/public stuff.

Comment: Don’t attempt to do “private/public stuff”; just put your methods on the prototype like normal and prefix private properties with an underscore.

Comment: @omega There are no private properties in JavaScript classes. You're assuming that the fact that you can use a class means the language has classical inheritance, but that's not the case, it only has prototypical inheritance which it uses to emulate classical inheritance. The only way to limit the visibility of an object is using Clousures.

Answer (score 5):

> This does not work, but is there a way I can access the parent function test()?

Because you're not using the prototype for the base class method, you can't use `super.test()` to reference it.  Instead, `this.test` is just a property of your current object.  If there's some reason you don't want to use the prototype for methods, you could do this:

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.test = function(){return 1;};
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
        let priorTest = this.test; 
        this.test = function(){alert(  priorTest.call(this)   );};
    }
}
```

To further explain, there's only one `this.test` property so when you assign `this.test = ...` in class B, you overwrite the previous `this.test` so you can't then refer to it in the implementation.  But, you can save its value before you overwrite it and then use that.

Also, some people mistakenly think that `this` refers to a different object inside a base class method vs. a derived class method.  That is not the case.  There's only one object and both the base class and derived class have methods on that object.  So, `this.test = xxx` in the base class refers to the exact same property as `this.test = yyy` in the derived class.  Methods defined on the prototype are actually saved on separate objects though so they can all exist independently.  When you reference `this.test` and there is no "own" property directly on the current object, then Javascript will search the prototype chain to see if it finds a property in the prototype chain with the desired name.  If it does, then it will return/execute that one.

---

The ES6 way to do this is to use the ES6 syntax for defining methods which will use the prototype and then you can use `super.test()` to refer to the base class implementation because in the prototype chain each class gets its own object on which to define methods that are searched if there is no "own" property with the specified name.

```
class A {
    constructor() {
    }
    test() {
        return 1;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super(); 
    }
    test() {
        alert(super.test());
    }
}
```

Comment: @omega - Did this answer your question?